# Is there a missing "qui" in this sentence?

Tags: grammaire

I found this in a French Facebook page:

> Les vrais amis sont les gens rares demandent de vos nouvelles et se soucient vraiment de la réponse.

Why does the "les gens rares" go immediately to a conjugated verb without a "qui"? Could someone help me understand this sentence?

I'd translate it literally as:

> Real friends are the few people ask about your news and really worry about the response.

Shouldn't the "demandent" be "qui demandent" or "demandant"?

Also why is there a "de" that follows after the "demandent"? Shouldn't it just be "demandent vos nouvelles"?

Comment: You are right. It should be "qui demandent". "Demandant" is also possible but it requires that you also change "se soucient" into "se souciant".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it's about a typo, not about French. You can ask such questions in the chat instead.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was a grammar rule that I hadn't known prior

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed a missing qui in this sentence.

> Les vrais amis sont les gens rares **qui** demandent de vos nouvelles et se soucient vraiment de la réponse.